# How to convert byte[ ] to CommonsMultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a following part of code in my Spring Boot App:

the `base64str` variable has a encode base 64 image,

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64str);
```

But I need to convert this array byte to `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile`

to then use this method (CommonsMultipartFile is an implementation of MultipartFile. That is why I used it).

```
AmazonClient.uploadFile(folder, MultipartFile)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There could be a few solutions:

1. I would check if there is not an overload to the `uploadFile` method that accepts something else than a `MultipartFile` or in case this is a custom class, maybe it could be modified, to accept something else.
2. You can write the ByteArray to the file system using `Files.write()` and then use the `CommonsMultipartFile` as intended. Don't forget to clean up the file later on or use a temp file mechanism.
3. It would actually be fairly easy to implement your own version of `MultipartFile`. The interface has only a few methods which can be easily created if you have a byte array.
4. There is actually a `MockMultipartFile` which also implements `MultipartFile` and just takes a byte array in the constructor. This is a bit of a dirty hack as it is meant for testing purposes only.